# My source code to calculate area and perimeter don't work

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript and i have probleme with poo and i have a problem to realise a permiter of cercle, if you can help me
thank you

```
class cercle {
  constructor(rayon) {
    this.rayon = rayon;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return Math.PI * this.rayon * this.rayon;
  }

  get perim() {
    return this.calcperim();
  }

  get calcperim() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.rayon;
  }
}

const cerc = new cercle(10);

console.log(cercle.area);
console.log(cercle.perim);
```

Comment: Please state your problem clearly.

Comment: You declare `cerc`, but invoke `cercle.area`, try `cerc.area`.

Answer (score 1):

You code seems OK but you missed the object `cerc` to `cercle`. Also remove the getter `get` from the method `calcperim()` or call it without parenthesis (`this.calcperim;`) if you want to use it as a getter.

The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

According to MDN [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Description).

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method calls. In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a `getter`. It is not possible to simultaneously have a `getter` bound to a property and have that property actually hold a value, although it is possible to use a `getter` and a setter in conjunction to create a type of pseudo-property.

```js
class circle {
    constructor(rayon) {
        this.rayon = rayon;
    }

    get area() {
        return this.calcArea();
    }

    calcArea() {
        return Math.PI * this.rayon * this.rayon;
    }
    
    get perim() {
        return this.calcperim();
    }

    calcperim() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.rayon;
    }
}

const cerc = new circle(10);

console.log(cerc.area);
console.log(cerc.perim);
```

Comment: I am seeing my answer is almost same as yours :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable name `cerc` was not used correctly and the function declaration `calcperim` was not right. Here is the working code:

```js
class cercle {
    constructor(rayon) {
        this.rayon = rayon;
    }

    get area() {
        return this.calcArea();
    }

    calcArea() {
        return Math.PI * this.rayon * this.rayon;
    }
    get perim() {

        return this.calcperim();
    }

    calcperim() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.rayon;
    }

}

const cerc = new cercle(10);

console.log(cerc.area);
console.log(cerc.perim);
```

Answer (score -1):

your issue is "this" keyword is referencing the window object.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
class cercle {
constructor(rayon) {
    this.rayon = rayon;
}

get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
}

calcArea() {
    return Math.PI * this.rayon * this.rayon;
}
get perim() {

    return this.calcperim();
}

calcperim() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.rayon;
}

}

const cerc = new cercle(10);

console.log(cerc.area);
console.log(cerc.perim);
```

[show this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DhbN.png)